# How to read D.update([E, ]**F) in the docs?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The docs of **dict.update** of Python reads as follows:

```
Help on method_descriptor:

update(...)
    D.update([E, ]**F) -> None.  Update D from dict/iterable E and F.
    If E is present and has a .keys() method, then does:  for k in E: D[k] = E[k]
    If E is present and lacks a .keys() method, then does:  for k, v in E: D[k] = v
    In either case, this is followed by: for k in F:  D[k] = F[k]
```

How is `[E, ]**F` meant? Are they two separate arguments and if so, why are they not comma separated?

Comment: `E` is optional (as indicated by the square brackets).  If `E` is present, then it has to be followed by a comma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation `[E, ]**F` indicates that the positional argument `E` is optional (all args within `[ ]` are optional, ie have a default value assigned in the method declaration), and that it accepts a variable number of keyword arguments as `F`. (This is usually called `**kwargs` in docs)

Within the method, `F` will be a `dict` containing all the keyword arguments as key-value pairs.